# Rename method in class body

Tags: python

Is it possible to rename method in Python?
Something like this

```
class Validation(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        super(Validation, self).__init__(methodName)
        #Doesn't work
        setattr(self,'do_folders_equal','test_do_folders_equal')
```

Rename method 'do_folders_equal' to 'test_do_folders_equal'..
 Usage above , obviously, is incorrect...How to do this hack?

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Why do you want this?

Comment: It was the only one way in my situation...Because of it seems to be not possible I hardcoded all the probable cases in class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't rename it, you'd just assign it to another variable:

`class Validation(unittest.TestCase):`

```
def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
    super(Validation, self).__init__(methodName)
    self.test_do_folders_equal = self.do_folders_equal
```

However there can sometimes be some weird interplay with inherited methods etc, so it sort of depends what you are trying to do.  Not sure how this behaves on old-style classes either...

EDIT: Or using a name read at runtime:

`class Validation(unittest.TestCase):`

```
def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
    super(Validation, self).__init__(methodName)
    setattr(self, 'test_do_folders_equal', getattr(self, 'do_folders_equal'))
```

Comment: No, it's not exact what I wanted. I retrieve string 'test_do_folders_equal' at runtime

Comment: Ok edited to add setattr and getattr, so you can use string names.